# Why the nonlinearity $f(x,\xi,\eta) = \lambda \xi - \xi^p + |\eta|^q$ satisfies $|f(x,\xi,\eta)| \leq c(|\xi|) (1+|\eta|^2)$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $p > 1$, $q \leq 2$, $\lambda \leq 0$ and $f(x,\xi,\eta) := \lambda \xi - \xi^p + |\eta|^q$ for $(x,\xi,\eta) \in \overline{\Omega} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^N$ with $\overline{\Omega} \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ a regular and bounded domain. Why $f$ satisfies $|f(x,\xi,\eta)| \leq c(|\xi|) (1+|\eta|^2)$ for some increasing function $c: \mathbb{R}_+ \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no dependence on $x$, is that what you want? Also, I guess you want $q\geq 0$, otherwise this will not be true. Can you elaborate where you are stuck?

Comment: I am reading [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/231962630_Existence_and_uniqueness_of_positive_solution_of_a_logistic_equation_with_nonlinear_gradient_term) and it was stated on page $562$ this inequality and I would like to know how to find the function $c$ in order to $f$ satisfies the inequality. By the way, $1 < q \leq 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$ \vert f(x,\xi, \eta) \vert \leq \vert \lambda \vert \cdot \vert \xi \vert + \vert \xi\vert^p + \vert \eta \vert^q. $$
For $1<q\leq 2$ we get
$$ \vert \eta \vert^q \leq 1 + \vert \eta \vert^2. $$
Hence, we have
$$ \vert f(x,\xi, \eta) \vert \leq (\vert \lambda \vert \cdot \vert\xi \vert + \vert \xi \vert^p \vert+1)(1+\vert \eta \vert^2). $$
That means, we can choose $c(\vert \xi \vert)=(\vert \lambda \vert \cdot \vert\xi \vert + \vert \xi \vert^p +1)$, which is clearly an increasing function (as $p\geq 0$). Note that this function is far from being unique.